Mac OS Mountain Lion 10.8 on VMWare Fusion
I have a MacBook Pro 2015 which is capable of running MacOS 12 but I've been stuck back at MacOS 10.14 Mojave just to keep my Adobe Creative Suite 6 running. I'd like to move the applications to a virtual machine running on 10.8 Mountain Lion (first version to support both 32-bit and native 64-bit apps).
I understand that 3D acceleration won't be supported but would the performance be comparable? Is it even possible?

I used to run a Parallels VM of El Capitan, specifically for running Creative Suite 6, on a 2018 Mini. Performance was adequate, though large, complex files, like lengthy InDesign documents with hundreds of pages of images, would be sluggish.
Performance will mostly depend on how much RAM and how many cores you have to divide between the VM and everything else. The VM image will also be quite large on your disk.
If you have the 13-inch 2015 MBP, then you've only got 2 cores, so performance will be very poor. Even the 15" is only 4-core, so you may experience some noticeable lag.

I'm sure you've heard this many times, but I'd urge you to look for alternatives. CS6 was released 12 years ago. There are now many modern apps that can match or exceed the capabilities of those versions.
If the logic board of your Mac fails tomorrow -- what plans do you have for ensuring that you can access your data?

I have Creative Suite 5 and Photoshop CS6 installed in Mojave on a 2018 Mac mini. I upgraded to Ventura by creating a triple boot arragement (Mojave, Ventura and Windows 11). I installed Parallels 18 in the host Ventura and added Yosemite as a guest. The host has 6 processors (cores) and 8 GB of memory. The guest was given 2 processors and 2048 MB of memory. I then installed Creative Suite 5 and Photoshop CS6 in Yosemite. This is what I learned.

I did not use the DVDs to install. I had already downloaded the installers and all updates released by Abobe. I believe at present these are difficult to get.

The I could not install all the available updates. Some updates require first upgrading from Yosemite to a newer OS X up to macOS Mojave.

InDesign and Illustrator were reported by others to work adequately in the VM, but not as well as when booted to Mojave.

Users of Photoshop thought the VM video was not adequate and preferred to to boot the original Mojave installation and run Photoshop from there.

Users did report problems getting the printers to work with Yosemite, but not with Mojave. I assumed this was because of Yosemite being must older that Mojave and not because of the Yosemite being installed in a VM.


